# Sitecore "Get Sitecore Item" getting all the items and I want to checkin only the changes

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

Actually I have done some sitecore changes in local Sitecore (Which is connecting to DEV) environment whih is the DEV Sitecore DB connections.

Now, I want to synch this. But for the first time, I am doing the "Get Sitecore Items including its children" for everything in the content.

As a result of that, the GIT shows all downloaded items to project rather than only the changed items by me.

How do I omit all files and take only my changed files for the GIT checkin? As there are around 20,000 files in GIT, I need a smart way to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Only sync the objects you are managing/changing.

Leave the system objects unsynchronised. Or if you do, have a different project for system objects (as you said there are a large number), and only update for upgrades etc.

This will not only simplify git so you only have objects you are managing, but you will also prevent having issues trying to upgrade sitecore in the future (and accidentally synchronizing old versions of sitecore items.

Comment: Russell, that is easy to think, even I thought the same. But I dont know how to do that. Coz, unless your object is there in project in the first place, you are not allowed to synch or see those items for synch

Comment: You can still sync the content node (and parent nodes) - just exclude all of the items that are not yours.

Comment: Ah, thats a nightmare as we got 30000 items or more

Comment: There are not a lot of other options - given the content is encoded when it is synchronized, Git can't help to manage changed files, especially when update timestamps are modified regularly.

Comment: Ok, then one last resort is, ignore all files thats with the "+" mark in GIT as its all added. I am not sure if that would help solve the problem. Just saw only few files being edited and 99% files added. Its crazy anyway